# Use a generic as a type without its type yet typescript

Tags: typescript

I've been the whole day trying to figure this out I could not.

I want to create a class that uses a generic type in its constructor without passing it the type yet:

```
//Tool.ts
export type ToolMethod<T> = (x: number, y: number, obj?: T) => void

export class Tool<T extends HTMLElement> {
  constructor(public element: T, public method: ToolMethod) {<-- /*Error here*/}
}

// or 

export class Tool<T extends HTMLElement, U extends ToolMethod> {
  constructor(public element: T, public method: U ){ /*Error ^ here too*/}
}
```

Because I want this:

```
//pencil.ts

const pencilElement = document.createElement('button')

const pencilMethod: ToolMethod<{/* some props */}> = (x,y, obj) => {
// ...
}

export const pencil = new Tool<HTMLButtonElement>(pencilElement, pencilMethod)

//or 

 export const pencil = new Tool<HTMLButtonElement, ToolMethod<{/*same props*/}>(pencilElement, pencilMethod)
```

I know that when I use a generic I have to pass a type, but I want to be able to specify that `method` has to be a `ToolMethod` without its type yet because the class still doesn't know it.
Like as `<T extends HTMLElement>`, I'm able to select the specific element that tool will have, since not all elements share the same props.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the class still doesn't know it*"? Then it needs to be generic on that itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Tool` class does need to be generic in two type parameters, but the second type parameter `U` doesn't need to be a `ToolMethod` itself; it could be the type parameter for `ToolMethod`:

```
export class Tool<T extends HTMLElement, U> {
  constructor(public element: T, public method: ToolMethod<U>) { }
}
```

Here, a `Tool<T, U>`'s `method` is a `ToolMethod<U>`.  You can see it working:

```
const pencilMethod: ToolMethod<SomeProps> = (x, y, obj) => { }

export const pencil = new Tool(pencilElement, pencilMethod)
// const pencil: Tool<HTMLButtonElement, SomeProps>
pencil.element; // HTMLButtonElement
pencil.method; // ToolMethod<SomeProps>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAqHtwGwOgFwM4CgCmAPADuATnABHAJ4Yp4TQCyKcAFuACYA8oAfHgLx4AUaAXHgDsArgFsARimwAaPIX7DxkmeDEArAPz9QASg5sAbuACW9JKkw58AYygBDBAjKQozPOjgoB9RwAlQFABkAUSgUEU84GQBVNgBvJDw8K3ABBDhsISs4HC4MITEoIys3UPCBOC0ZPIKivHDaBi1nKgamGN1YvABfJB6kZNT8EgErIygQsIiOPHpwK1EImCtsFFsPCbK4LgByMSE4bIFt7TMjcskAM1srUgBlcHCABWxwDEd4xL48NOwzgHMANwJWTyUQSbBAxIAL34YmcqwEQL6AzSeGGoygLTo9CalGo2MY9yeLzebE4PBkhGUal07Di3TM6CwuCSKVR6LG0wEKAA7k5oLlPBiNhEqkKxliGCcQKzBmjxVBcS4-IEAEL7Q4i8oyIkoZ6vBAsJAc2AoUoRAF4GUqgLqg4pLVwY0KmD1bGWmXkTH4hiEh56kmGoA)

Answer (score 0):

I think You are looking for this:

```js
// T is defined as function generic argument instead of type itself
export type ToolMethod = <T>(x: number, y: number, obj?: T) => void

export class Tool<T extends HTMLElement> {
  constructor(public element: T, public method: ToolMethod) { // no error here anymore

  }
}
```

You can define generic argument directly for function.